# Powershell to return MFA Status for mailboxes

Tags: powershell, office365

Working on a simple powershell script that will grab all mailboxes and their MFA status and drop it into an excel sheet.

Because of AD sync, all my users have a license, but only a few hundred have mailboxes in O365 at the moment. So I'd like to pull a list of mailboxes and return the mfastatus.

Here's what I got. It doesn't error but returns all mailboxes as disabled MFA.

```
Connect-MsolService

$Result=@() 
$mailbox = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -RecipientTypeDetails UserMailbox
$mailbox | ForEach-Object {
$mailbox = $_
    if ($mailbox.StrongAuthenticationRequirements.State -ne $null){
    $mfaStatus = $mailbox.StrongAuthenticationRequirements.State
    }
        else {
            $mfaStatus = "Disabled"}

$Result += New-Object PSObject -property @{ 
        UserName = $mailbox.DisplayName
        UserPrincipalName = $mailbox.UserPrincipalName
        MFAStatus = $mfaStatus
    }
    $Result | Select UserName,UserPrincipalName,MFAStatus |
    Export-CSV "D:\\O365-Users-MFA-Status.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
}
```

Comment: have you made sure that the mailbox object has the attribute you are checking? In the docs i can´t find it. You could try to just get it via `Get-MsolUser` with the identities you get from `Get-mailbox`

Comment: Thanks Paul. I realized that was my failure right after I clicked "post". So now I'm trying to use get-msoluser to return only users that have a mailbox. Cheers.